# jquery.css background image not appending

Tags: jquery, css, image, dynamic, background

I seem to be having difficulty pulling up a dynamic image as a background image for a div. I've tried several things but all have failed.

The url does pull up in the console log and this does work when appended as an image, just not as a background img. The ID appends but it's as if it didn't even read the background image css.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

var heroImage = [
                    {

                    }

                ];

var itemList = [
                        {
                          "itemImage": "../images/trend/greenpants.jpg",

                          "itemName": "Green Pants",

                          "itemType": "pants", "itemClass":

                          "trend", "itemDep" : "male"

                        },
                        {

                          "itemImage":"../images/collection/whitecoat.jpg",

                          "itemName" : "Snow Coat",

                          "itemType": "coat",

                          "itemClass": "collection",

                          "itemDep" : "female"

                        }

                ];



 for (var i = 0, len = itemList.length; i < len; i++)

      {

        if (itemList[i].itemDep === "female")

        {

          console.log(itemList[i].itemImage);

          let image = itemList[i].itemImage;


        let stockDiv = $('<div id = "stockDiv">');

            $('#stockItem').css({"background-image": "url("+image+")"});

            $(".gallery").append(stockDiv);

        }

    }

});
```

I have also tried it as

```
$('#stockItem').css("background-image": "url(" + image + ")");
```

and it fails.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Did you try `$('#stockItem').css("background-image": "url('" + image + "')");`

Answer (score 0):

You did not close stockDiv in your query string. The background image, I think, was not set to the right element. I changed it to stockDiv. Below is an updated snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var heroImage = [{

    }

  ];

  var itemList = [{
      "itemImage": "../images/trend/greenpants.jpg",

      "itemName": "Green Pants",

      "itemType": "pants",
      "itemClass":

        "trend",
      "itemDep": "male"

    },
    {

      "itemImage": "../images/collection/whitecoat.jpg",

      "itemName": "Snow Coat",

      "itemType": "coat",

      "itemClass": "collection",

      "itemDep": "female"

    }

  ];


  for (var i = 0, len = itemList.length; i < len; i++)

  {

    if (itemList[i].itemDep === "female")

    {

      console.log(itemList[i].itemImage);

      let image = itemList[i].itemImage;


      let stockDiv = $('<div id = "stockDiv"></div>');
      stockDiv.css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + image + ')');

      $(".gallery").append(stockDiv);

    }

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gallery">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gracie -- Background image is coming .I think you need to give styles . i have load same code in html and it worked .

```
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #stockItem {
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
      color: red
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

      var heroImage = [{

        }

      ];

      var itemList = [{
          "itemImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",

          "itemName": "Green Pants",

          "itemType": "pants",
          "itemClass":

            "trend",
          "itemDep": "male"

        },
        {

          "itemImage": "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff",

          "itemName": "Snow Coat",

          "itemType": "coat",

          "itemClass": "collection",

          "itemDep": "female"

        }

      ];



      for (var i = 0, len = itemList.length; i < len; i++)

      {

        if (itemList[i].itemDep === "female")

        {

          console.log('chandan', itemList[i].itemImage);

          let image = itemList[i].itemImage;


          let stockDiv = $('<div id = "stockDiv">');
          console.log(stockDiv)
          $('#stockItem').css({
            "background-image": "url('" + image + "')"
          });
          $(".gallery").append(stockDiv);

        }

      }

    });
  </script>
  <div id="stockDiv">
    <div id="stockItem">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Chadan! I am actually using Sass to build this, although the .css is linked. Not sure if that could be mucking up the waters. The .stockItem does have styles in my scss and I am getting the inset to show up. I'l give this a whirl!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your JavaScript I'm assuming that **#stockItem** and **.gallery** are two DIVs already in your HTML before the script runs? Or is **#stockItem** a typo that's trying to grab the **#stockDiv** you made on the line above it?

Assuming that **#stockDiv** and **#stockItem** were not typos, I wrote the following HTML and the background loaded fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #stockItem, #stockDiv, .gallery {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }

  </style>
  <script>
    // (Your script here)
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="gallery"></div>
  <div id="stockItem"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if that's *not* what you meant, and you're trying to attach the background directly to **#stockDiv** before inserting it, then this might be what you're looking for:

```
for (var i = 0, len = itemList.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (itemList[i].itemDep === "female") {
    console.log(itemList[i].itemImage);

    let image = itemList[i].itemImage;

    let stockDiv = $('<div id = "stockDiv">').css({"background-image": "url("+image+")"});

    $(".gallery").append(stockDiv);
  }
}
```

Both of the above snippets work. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Reagan, these are dynamically created divs and I need it to stay that way for how I'm setting up the images. I went back and tried it that way but it still fails. Not sure what's going on here. I'm writing this in sass, could that be the problem?

Comment: The second snippet above does what you were trying to do & does it with dynamic images, so I don't think the dynamic images part is the problem you're seeing.

The second issue -- pointed out by @chandan above -- is that a DIV with a background image doesn't have any height or width if you don't specify it in CSS (or SASS), so without height or width it won't appear.  The HTML example above has a height and width, which is another reason why I was able to see it working.

Did you set the height and width on your DIV?

Answer (score 0):

Reagan's answer worked. Turns out it was working when I used that code but needed padding. Was able to give it a class dynamically and add that padding.

Thanks so much!